# BCP Insert through View vs Manual insert

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Consider the following code

```
use tempdb
go

drop table if exists ImportTest1;
create table ImportTest1 (
 Column1    int null,
 Column2 int null,
 NewColumn int null
);
insert into ImportTest1 select 1,2,3 union select 4,5,6;
select * from ImportTest1;

drop table if exists DestinationTest1;
create table DestinationTest1 (
Column1 int null,
Column2 int null
);
select * from DestinationTest1;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER VIEW TestView1 AS 
SELECT Column1 AS Column1, Column2 AS Column2, NULL AS NewColumn FROM DestinationTest1
GO
```

If we run this

```
INSERT INTO TestView1 (Column1, Column2, NewColumn)
SELECT Column1, Column2, NewColumn FROM ImportTest1
```

It fails with error

```
Update or insert of view or function 'TestView1' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.
```

However, if I do the same thing through BCP, it works fine

```
BCP "SELECT Column1, Column2, NewColumn FROM tempdb..ImportTest1" QUERYOUT C:\BCPTest\test.txt -T -c -t,

BCP tempdb..TestView1 IN C:\BCPTest\test.txt -T -c -t,
```

What is happening here that allows BCP to import successfully through the view but we cannot run that manually?

Comment: You can do this in a regular db as well, I just did tempdb for posting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bcp` is an ODBC API application.

It does application-style things, as opposed to being a simple T-SQL command:

In your example, bcp runs:

```
exec sp_describe_first_result_set N'select * from tempdb..TestView1'

declare @p1 int
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,NULL,N'select * from tempdb..TestView1',1
select @p1

insert bulk tempdb..TestView1([Column1] int,[Column2] int)

exec sp_unprepare 1
```

So essentially, it is working out which columns are valid to insert to before running the bulk insert (using API syntax).